# Noscript блок, ломается если внутри него теги

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо добавить контент блок для роботов, если JS отключен, с помощью `<noscript></noscript>`, но он выдает [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK3WV.png) и [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UbKr.png). Я понял, что внутрь `noscript` нельзя добавлять теги, только текст. Как решить такую проблему тогда?

Comment: Внутрь `<noscript></noscript>` можно добавлять какие угодно теги: https://jsfiddle.net/4oqfu9jw/ Приведите пример Вашего кода - без него непонятно, откуда и почему берутся ошибки и какое отношение они имеют к noscript

Comment: Если я правильно понял по скринам, вы пытаетесь добавить контент в `<noscript>` через JavaScript. Это чисто физически невозможно т.к. содержимое `<noscript>` будет использоваться только в случае отсутствия поддержки JavaScript.

Comment: @7-zete-7 проект у меня на nuxt, в template пишу `<noscript><span>test</span></noscript>`. Ну без тегов ведь работает

Comment: @Gleb, судя по скринам, добавление элементов делается почему-то всё равно на фронте. Или у вас подключен отладчик сервера? Есть предположение что этот контент не рендерится на сервере, а отдаётся фронту на рисование. Попробуйте смотреть только текстовый ответ от сервера (через Ctrl+U, например). Что бы контент был в `<noscript>` он должен быть в получаемом HTML сразу же (в текстовом ответе).

Comment: @7-zete-7 Откладчик не включен. Да, всё что внутри `<noscript>`, я получаю текстом (когда включен JS). У меня появляются ошибки, при включенном JS.

Comment: @Gleb, как раз оба понятия "получаю текстом" и "когда включен JS" несовместимы в контексте того что я предложить. Попробуйте открывать страницу не как HTML, а как простой текст (хотя бы даже дописав перед адресом `view-source:`, например `view-source:https://google.com/`). Контент должен быть в `<noscript>` именно в таком представлении. На ходу добавлять элементы не имеет смысла.

Comment: @7-zete-7 да так и открывал, внутри `noscript` всё содержание обычным текстом идет включая теги

Comment: Гугл предложил https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2582 где в свою очередь предлагают писать `<noscript inline-template>...`

Comment: @Mike Не плохой вариант, но получается при включенном JS будет видно данный блок в коде. Я решил данную проблему в сообщение написал

Comment: @Gleb рекомендую решение данной проблемы оформлять не в теле вопроса, а отдельным ответом, помеченным как верным.

Comment: @4500zenja Спасибо!

Comment: Не и ещё не забудье поставить галочку, чтобы вопрос не висел как "нерешённый" :)

Comment: _но получается при включенном JS будет видно данный блок в коде_ @Gleb, если стили тега `<noscript>` не менялись, то его содержимое не должно быть видно пользователям при включённом JavaScript. Наличие в нём контента не должно быть проблемой.

Comment: @7-zete-7 Пользователями не видно, но в коде есть этот блок, для SEO возможно плохо будет

Comment: @Gleb, скрывая контент через код в ответе от SEO содержимое тега `<noscript>` так же никуда не денется. Складывается ощущение что вам не до конца понятно, [для чего и как используется тег `<noscript>`](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-noscript-element--cms-25498) и [как он должен использоваться относительно SEO](https://prognote.ru/web-dev/layout/noscript-tag-what-are-they-and-how-do-they-affect-seo/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил данную проблему таким способом:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!JSenabled">test</div>
<template/>

data: () => ({
  JSenabled: false,
}),
mounted() {
  this.JSEnabled = typeof window !== 'undefined'
},
```